# Error 2003 is Occurring when connecting MYSql through SQL yog tool

Tags: mysql, database-administration

i couldn't able to login to my mysql database through SQLyog tool.The screen shot of the error is shown below and i can login the database through SSH Secure Shell.
 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.My ip table is blocking the sqlyog to access server.changed the configuration in the ip table config file and it works smoothly.